# Decomposing exterior power via complex structure

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

I guess the following is very easy to answer for someone knowledgeable in algebra: Consider a real even-dimensional vector space $V$ of (real) dimension $d=2n$. Furthermore, we consider a linear complex structure $J:V\to V$ on $V$. This provides a (complex?) direct sum decomposition
$$V_{\mathbb{C}}=V_{+}\oplus V_{-}$$
where $V_{\pm}:=\{v\in V\mid J(v)=\pm i v\}$ denote the eigenspaces of $J$. Now, this is usually used to decompose the complexified exterior power as follows:
$$\bigg(\bigwedge^{k}V\bigg)_{\mathbb{C}}=\bigoplus_{r+s=d}\bigwedge^{r,s}V\quad where\quad \bigwedge^{r,s}V:=\bigg(\bigwedge^{k}V_{+}\bigg)\wedge \bigg(\bigwedge^{k}V_{-}\bigg)$$
Now, I was wondering: In the right-hand side of this decomposition, are we taking $\bigwedge_{\mathbb{R}}$ or $\bigwedge_{\mathbb{C}}$? I was looking in the literature, but I did not find a definit answer. I know that the l.h.s. is more preicsely given by
$${\bigwedge^{k}}_{\mathbb{C}}V_{\mathbb{C}}\cong\bigg({\bigwedge^{k}}_{\mathbb{R}}V\bigg)_{\mathbb{C}}.$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All the exterior products are complex: It is a general fact that for any $\mathbb{F}$-vector space $V$ with $V=U\oplus W$ for linear subspaces $U,W$, where $\mathbb{F}$ is an arbitrary field, there is a canonical isomorphism
$${\bigwedge^{k}}_{\mathbb{F}}V\cong\bigoplus_{r+s=k}\bigg\{\bigg({\bigwedge^{r}}_{\mathbb{F}}U\bigg)\otimes_{\mathbb{F}}\bigg({\bigwedge^{s}}_{\mathbb{F}}W\bigg)\bigg\}$$
Hence, the decomposition you stated is obtained by applying this decomposition to
$${\bigwedge^{k}}_{\mathbb{C}}V_{\mathbb{C}}$$
and $V_{\mathbb{C}}=V_{+}\oplus V_{-}$.